# re-translate a link to the proper directory

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirection

We have a folder on our website http://openeye.net/imagesa that's full of garbage data that  external sites and half of the company uses as a dump directory. I'm planning on ultimately nuking it completely but in the meantime I'd like to move it to downloads.openeye.net. The problem I'm having is that many of the users will still have a link similar to http://openeye.net/imagesa/filename.duh.

I'm looking for both an Apache and IIS7 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.htaccess` or your apache virtual host:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectRule ^imagesa/(.*) http://downloads.openeye.net/$1 [R]
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a ton. If I were running IIS7 how would this be accomplished? (we have two sites one running IIS and the other Apache)

Comment: You'll have to get an IIS guy to pitch in for that one. Perhaps edit yoru question with a note at the end saying you are looking for both IIS and Apache solutions.